# Issue with my C program : compilation error occurs

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

I am using Yocto project cross-compiler to compile my C code.

But for some reasons I have compilation errors.

This is my C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa.hpp"

/* MRAA does not yet understand GPIO-A - GPIO-L       */
/* Linaro will add this                   */
/* What Mraa does understand is pin out numbers so,     */
/* pin 23 is GPIO-A and pin 25 is GPIO-C          */

#define LED 10
#define BUTTON 29

bool running = true;
bool led_state = false;
int last_touch;
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        running = false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mraa::Result ret;
    int touch;

    mraa::Gpio* touch_gpio = new mraa::Gpio(BUTTON);
    if (touch_gpio == NULL){
        return mraa::ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }
    mraa::Gpio* led_gpio = new mraa::Gpio(LED);
    if (led_gpio == NULL){
        return mraa::ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

    if ((ret = touch_gpio->dir(mraa::DIR_IN))!= mraa::SUCCESS){
        return ret;
    }
    if ((ret = led_gpio->dir(mraa::DIR_OUT))!= mraa::SUCCESS){
        return ret;
    }

    led_gpio->write(led_state);

    while (running) {
        touch = touch_gpio->read();
        if (touch == 1 && last_touch == 0) {
            led_state = !led_state;
            ret = led_gpio->write(led_state);
            usleep(100000);
        }
        last_touch = touch;
        usleep(1);
    }
    delete led_gpio;
    delete touch_gpio;
    return ret;
}
```

This is the Makefile :

```
#CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a5 --sysroot=/opt/poky-atmel/2.5.3/sysroots/cortexa5hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
#CC="gcc"

all: last1.o
        ${CC} last1.o -o target_bin -lmraa

last1.o: last1.c
        ${CC} -I . -c last1.c

clean:
        rm -rf *.o
        rm target_bin
```

And this is what I get when i run `make all` :

> In file included from
>   /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa/common.hpp:28:0,
>                    from /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa.hpp:27,
>                    from last1.c:4:
>
> /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa/types.hpp:32:1:
>   error: unknown type name ‘namespace’  namespace mraa  ^~~~~~~~~
>
> /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa/types.hpp:33:1:
>   error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘{’
>   token  {  ^
>
> In file included from
>   /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa.hpp:27:0,
>                    from last1.c:4: /home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa/common.hpp:29:10:
>   fatal error: string: No such file or directory  #include 
>             ^~~~~~~~
>
> compilation terminated. Makefile:8: recipe for target 'last1.o' failed
>   make: *** [last1.o] Error 1

Comment: Sounds like you are compiling C++ code with a C compiler.

Comment: You need to take a few steps back and go back to whatever book or tutorial you have been using. You're not programming in C, but in the totally different language C++.

Comment: Change `#CC="gcc"` to `CC="g++"` in the Makefile to compile you code with a c++ compiler

Comment: @Chelmy88 Doesn't matter as long as the source file have the `.c` suffix.

Comment: Thank you all of you. I have just edited the source file from .c to .cpp and re compiled. I have passed these compilation errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, tanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are compiling your code written in `C` with a `C++` compiler.
Just change your `.c` files to `.cpp` files, and compile using `g++` rather than `gcc` if you are on Unix systems.